# October CMS Routing

Tags: php, routes, octobercms

I'm trying to configure routes in my OctoberCMS app. I configure routes in Plugin.php file of my plugin.
At the moment my code:

```
public function boot()
    {

        Validator::extend('numeric_for_repeater', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
            foreach ($value as $v)
            {
                $validator = Validator::make(
                    $v,
                    [
                        'stock_quantity' => 'sometimes|numeric',
                        'stock_votes_quantity' => 'sometimes|numeric',
                        'value' => 'sometimes|numeric',
                    ],
                    $parameters
                );
                if ($validator->fails())
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        });

        \Route::get('/oferty/{id}', function ($id = null) {

            $theme =  Theme::getActiveTheme();
            $path = \Config::get('cms.themesPath', '/themes').'/'.$theme->getDirName();
            $this->assetPath = $path;
            $offer = new Offer();
        return \View::make(self::MAMF_PAGE_DIR . 'oferta.htm', ['offer' => $offer->getOfferById($id)]);

        });
    }
```

but I got an error: 
`View [.var.www.plugins.mamf.mamf2017..........themes.mamf2017.pages.oferta.htm] not found.` because by default October expects views files in plugin directory.
How can I render view outside of plugin dir, for ex in `themes` path like this `app/themes/mamf2017/pages/oferta.htm`

Comment: Two points: 1- You can create a file called `routes.php` in the root directory of your plugin and put your routing code in there. 2- Do you really need to render your pages this way? You can create a page in your `themes` directory and specify its address `/oferty/{id}` at the top of the page.

Comment: I see no difference between creating file routes.php or editing Plugin.php cause both of this files are placed in root dir of my plugin. And I really don't want to put all - configuration, logic and view - in one file cause I think it stupid idea and I what to separate it in normal way

Answer (score 0):

I guess **self::MAMF_PAGE_DIR** is full base path your application. for example like

**/var/www/vhosts/octdev/themes/responsiv-flat/**

In short **\View::make** need absolute path from root

now it will try to look file with configured extensions for october-cms its **.htm**. others are **.blade** and **.htm.blade** etc ..

so in your case (view)file name is **'oferta.htm'** that .(dot) is translated to '/' path separator so just don't use it and just use ***'oferta'*** so it will check all possible values in pages directory

- oferta.htm
- oferta.blade
- oferta.htm.balde

this adding .htm is automatic thing so you just need to provide name of view then it will find and work automatically

```
\Route::get('/oferty/{id}', function ($id = null) {

        $theme =  \Cms\Classes\Theme::getActiveTheme();
        $path = \Config::get('cms.themesPath', '/themes').'/'.$theme->getDirName();
        $this->assetPath = $path;
        $offer = new Offer();
        return \View::make(base_path() . $path . '/pages/' . 'oferta', ['offer' => $offer->getOfferById($id)]);

    });
```

this is tested and working fine hope this will help you.
if its not working please comment.

Comment: I will check it and let you know. Thanks