# Laravel with October CMS

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I'm using October CMS with Laravel.
But I don't know how to insert the data to view.
This is my code from my route.

```
    Route::post('/sendmail', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, \Illuminate\Mail\Mailer $mailer) {
//function(vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer $mailer)
  $mailer
  ->to('test@test.com')//specify where to send
  ->send( new SendMail(
    $request->input('name'),
    $request->input('email'),
    $request->input('message')
  ));

  return redirect()->back();
})->name('sendmail');
```

And here is my SendMail.php

```
class SendMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $msg;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($name, $email, $msg )
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->msg = $msg;

    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        //dump($this);
        //exit;
        return $this
        ->from('cebpac-autoloan@noreply-unionbank.com')
        // ->from('customer.service@unionbankph.com')
        ->view('email.send');
    }
```

But the problem is that I cannot insert the data to the view because of this error

**View [email.send] not found.**

**throw new InvalidArgumentException("View [$name] not found.");**

The files are inside my "plugins" of October CMS

Comment: check config/view.php, if it's standard laravel, you can find place for your view.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are facing same problem like here:

please look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47197399/3076866

you need to provide full absolute path of the view

```
/var/www/etc/extra/plugin/.../yourplugin/<view_folder>/email/send
```

we assume that **email** is directory and **send** is view name.

please comment if it's not working with errors :)

Comment: I'll try this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make it a bit cleaner by targeting the email view like so:

```
pluginauthor.pluginname::email.send
```

Although I think OcotberCms requires you to name your view folder 'views'

On a recent project I had this working with my mail views structured like so:

```
/views/mail/{{email template name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can overwrite the path of view path by creating
config/view.php

Inside view.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | View Storage Paths
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Most templating systems load templates from disk. Here you may specify
    | an array of paths that should be checked for your views. Of course
    | the usual Laravel view path has already been registered for you.
    |
    */

    'paths' => [
        // Default Laravel Blade template location
        // realpath(base_path('resources/views'))
        realpath(base_path('plugins/a/b/views/pdf'))
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Compiled View Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines where all the compiled Blade templates will be
    | stored for your application. Typically, this is within the storage
    | directory. However, as usual, you are free to change this value.
    |
    */

    'compiled' => realpath(storage_path('framework/views')),

];
```